# prevent ?DeleteDocument URL option for Domino

Tags: lotus-domino

I store attachments in a Notes document and based upon the field value of a parent document I would prevent that users could user the ?DeleteDocument URL option somehow.

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSVRGU_9.0.1/basic/H_ABOUT_DOMINO_URL_COMMANDS_4332.html

The user is registered as Author on the document containing the attachments.

What options do I have?

Comment: ACL- Remove the "delete documents" rights on the DB and implement your own soft delete function. I normally set a Field "Deleted" to the current timestamp and filter all relevant views with ... & deleted=""  .. So the authors are still able to move things into trash...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've implemented this in two ways.

Like [umeli](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1186924/umeli) wrote, in the ACL remove the "delete documents" rights from **people**, but finesse this by allowing **servers** to retain deletion rights.

In a CRM database I set the Database Script QueryDocumentDelete routine to assign 'continue' the value 'False'.  If the user is in the Notes Client, then give them a dialog with something like "Please raise a Support Request with a justification to delete this document".  Operations could then set the form field to 'Garbage' and **server** automation would delete the document on schedule.

In an SaaS application a soft-delete similar to the technique [umeli](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1186924/umeli) suggests was implemented.